# JavaFX StackedBarChart negative bar not showing

Tags: java, javafx

The bBar with a negative value does not show on the chart. Any solution?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColoredStackBarChart extends Application {

    private BarChart<String, Number> chart;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        this.chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        this.chart.setAnimated(false);

        this.chart.setBarGap(0);
        this.chart.setCategoryGap(0);

        StackedBarChart<String, Number> chart = new StackedBarChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setLegendVisible(false);

        xAxis.getCategories().addAll("A", "B");

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        XYChart.Data aBar = new XYChart.Data("A", 100);
        series1.getData().add(aBar);

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        XYChart.Data bBar = new XYChart.Data("B", -100);
        series2.getData().add(bBar);

        chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

        // NOTE can only set colors after they have been added to the chart.
        aBar.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        bBar.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");


        VBox vbox = new VBox(this.chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: faintly remember that this is a bug (might be fixed recently) - and I have seen hacks (maybe in 3rd party frameworks), a bit of research might bring them up :)

Comment: I don't know if this will help any but look into https://github.com/GSI-CS-CO/chart-fx